# Updating django model with highest value in json array

Tags: python, json, django, list

The issue I'm running into is that I would like to update a Django model with json values. The trouble is that some of the values in the json are a lists with multiple numbers.

This is what the json looks like:

```
json = {'fields': {'resources': [], 'initiative': [8, 21, 22]}, 'pk': 81}
{'fields': {'resources': [], 'initiative': [5, 8, 22]}, 'pk': 82}
{'fields': {'resources': [], 'initiative': [8, 22]}, 'pk': 83}
{'fields': {'resources': [], 'initiative': [6]}, 'pk': 84}

def update_model():
    for row in json:
Model.objects.filter(id=row['pk']).update(initiative_id=row['fields']['initiative'][0], resources_id=row['fields']['resources'][0])
```

I can't figure how to get the Model line spaced correctly on Stack.

Anyway, when I run this I get "IndexError: list index out of range" presumably because this method can only handle a list with 1 value.

I need the highest value in the arrays for resources and initiatives to update Model with.

Model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=False)
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform, blank=True)
    standard_type = models.ForeignKey(StandardType, default=SetDefaults.set_standard_type_default, blank=True)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(Owner, blank=True)
    evaluated_by = models.ForeignKey(Evaluator, blank=True, default=SetDefaults.set_default_evaluator())
    business_driver= models.ManyToManyField(BusinessDriver, blank=True)
    initiative = models.ForeignKey(Initiative, null=True, blank=True)
    solution = models.ManyToManyField(Solution, blank=True)
    point_of_contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True, default=SetDefaults.set_default_contact, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    required_by = models.ForeignKey(LifecycleStage, null=False, default=SetDefaults.set_required_by_default, blank=True)
    resources = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, blank=True)
    change_notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    change_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want to assign only first value from initiative or resources list if exists:

```
def update_model():
    for row in json:
        initiative = row['fields']['initiative']
        resources = row['fields']['resources']

        initiative_id = max(initiative) if initiative else None
        resources_id = max(resources) if resources else None

        Model.objects.filter(id=row['pk']).update(
            initiative_id=initiative_id, 
            resources_id=resources_id
        )
```

Comment: Hi Ivan. Based on the way I setup the question, I can see why you would assume I only want the first value. I do actually want all of the values in the array, which is the source of my frustration with this problem. Do you know how to get all of them in there?

Comment: I have updated. I'm a new user of Stack and I cannot figure out how to space code correctly on here but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: How do you plan to save all values in array if you have `ForeignKey` which accepts one value? You might want `ManyToManyField` for resources and initiative?

Comment: You are correct and honestly, I completely forgot that a ForeignKey only accepts one value. At this point, what I'd like is to take the highest value in the array. I've edited the question to reflect that.